# subtracting the mean of each row in numpy with broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy

I try to subtract the mean of each row of a matrix in numpy using broadcasting but I get an error. Any idea why?

Here is the code:

```
from numpy import *
X = random.rand(5, 10)
Y = X - X.mean(axis = 1)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,10) (5,)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Now can you explain why `X - X.mean(axis=0)` works without the `keepdims` parameter? :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The `mean` method is a *reduction* operation, meaning it converts a 1-d collection of numbers to a single number.  When you apply a reduction to an n-dimensional array along an axis, numpy collapses that dimension to the reduced value, resulting in an (n-1)-dimensional array.  In your case, since `X` has shape (5, 10), and you performed a reduction along axis 1, you end up with an array with shape (5,):

```
In [8]: m = X.mean(axis=1)

In [9]: m.shape
Out[9]: (5,)
```

When you try to subtract this result from `X`, you are trying to subtract an array with shape (5,) from an array with shape (5, 10).  These shapes are not compatible for [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#broadcasting).  (Take a look at [the description of broadcasting in the User Guide](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).)

For broadcasting to work the way you want, the result of the `mean` operation should be an array with shape (5, 1) (to be compatible with the shape (5, 10)).  In recent versions of numpy, the reduction operations, including `mean`, have an argument called `keepdims` that tells the function to not collapse the reduced dimension.  Instead, a trivial dimension with length 1 is kept:

```
In [10]: m = X.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)

In [11]: m.shape
Out[11]: (5, 1)
```

With older versions of numpy, you can use `reshape` to restore the collapsed dimension:

```
In [12]: m = X.mean(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)

In [13]: m.shape
Out[13]: (5, 1)
```

So, depending on your version of numpy, you can do this:

```
Y = X - X.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

or this:

```
Y = X - X.mean(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for performance, you can also consider using [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) that is supposedly faster than actually using `np.sum` or `np.mean`. Thus, the desired output could be obtained like so -

```
X - np.einsum('ij->i',X)[:,None]/X.shape[1]
```

Please note that the `[:,None]` part is similar to `keepdims` to keep the dimensions of it same as that of the input array. This could also be used in broadcasting.

**Runtime tests**

1) Comparing just the `mean` calculation -

```
In [47]: X = np.random.rand(500, 1000)

In [48]: %timeit X.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.5 ms per loop

In [49]: %timeit X.mean(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.52 ms per loop

In [50]: %timeit np.einsum('ij->i',X)[:,None]/X.shape[1]
1000 loops, best of 3: 832 µs per loop
```

2) Comparing entire calculation -

```
In [52]: X = np.random.rand(500, 1000)

In [53]: %timeit X - X.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.56 ms per loop

In [54]: %timeit X - X.mean(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.54 ms per loop

In [55]: %timeit X - np.einsum('ij->i',X)[:,None]/X.shape[1]
100 loops, best of 3: 6.18 ms per loop
```